# What is CLANG indexing and why is it slow?

Tags: c++, qt, indexing, compilation

I setup an older PC (with 2GB memory) and wanted to try to use that as a compiling machine to free up my laptop.  But, what takes 2 minutes to build on my new laptop takes over 1/2 hour on the old pc!

I'm working in Qt Creator on both machines, and on the old PC it shows "Indexing with clangd" and counts from 1 to 516 (number of files in my project), but that steps takes 30 minutes!

1. What is the "indexing with clangd" step?
2. Why is it SO SLOW?  HTOP shows 20% free memory, and the CPU's are averaging 70%
3. Any tips on how to speed this up?

Comment: [What is clangd?](https://clangd.llvm.org/)

Comment: In general, code indexers are hungry beasts that'll eat every resource they can. That the CPU's not pinned likely means it's IO bound reading through all of your source files and the headers they include.

Comment: If you're only compiling do you really need to use creator? Can't you just use the build tools directly? Then you wouldn't encounter the indexer at all

Comment: I need to step through code, so I prefer to with Qt Creator's debugger UI.  (I need to debug my code using a portable computer).  But I don't understand how it is so constrained.  All code is kept on a server (NFS share), both computers  on 100M links...and CPU and memory capacity remains unused.  What's the constraint?

Comment: @TSG: "*What's the constraint?*" The fact that it's across the network on a server. Sure, you've got a pretty fast connection, but it's not as fast as a local harddrive.

Comment: So the older PC is not just a build machine.

Comment: @NicolBolas My laptop runs across the network and is compiles in <2 min (vs 30+ min) so it's not a network problem or file share problem.  I need to debug (compile > run > compile > run > etc) in a remote environment so I want to setup a machine there.

Comment: Does your PC still have an HDD and your laptop an SSD perhaps?

Comment: @PepijnKramer No...starting to think just raw CPU power (though it's not pinned at 100%)

Comment: Ok always good to take measurements and find your bottlenecks that way. Have you checked the number of page faults? It could just be your virtual memory starts trashing